# alternative to stuff function in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012

i have table Tab1 like below( my actual table has upto 20,000 rows

```
a     b      c    statecode
-------------------------------------------
A1   abc   def    FL          
B1   abc   def    AZ
C1   abc   def    MI
D1   abc   def    CO
E1   abc   def    IL
F1   abc   def    CA
```

Here is what i am trying to do: for a given combination of columns b and c if there exists multiple rows then i want to concatenate a comma delimited  "a - statecode".

i need a result like below...

```
a     b      c    statecode   output
-------------------------------------------
A1   abc   def      FL          A1-FL,B1-AZ,C1-MI,D1-CO,E1-IL,F1-CA
```

What i tried:
I tried sql stuff function for this

```
SELECT a, b,c,
  STUFF((SELECT  distinct ', '+ t1.a +'-'+ t1.statecode
             FROM Tab1 t1
             where  t2.b = t1.a
             and    t2.c= t1.c 
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1,'') AS output
from Tab1 t2;
```

This works fine for relatively small tables, my actual table has 20,000 rows and 15 columns, i have to check equality for a combination of 10 columns(like b,c in this example there are 8 more).

Is there a better way to do this in sql?or improve performance of stuff function?

Comment: I faced the same problem and searching for answers and arrived here. When I read that the stuff was not the case, I tried playing around my query and what I did was to Left Join the whole XML Sub Select to the main query.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here isn't the `stuff()` function.  It's the subquery and the XML processing.

There really isn't an alternative in SQL Server.  I mean, there are two other possible ways to do aggregate string concatenation:  write your own UDF or, if you only have a handful of values, use `row_number()` and string concatenation.

Before going down that route, try to optimize your query.  The first thing to do is to create an index on `tab1(a, c)`.

As a note:  it is better to write this using an explicit XML tag.  The syntax is very similar:

```
SELECT a, b,c,
  STUFF((SELECT  distinct ', '+ t1.a +'-'+ t1.statecode
             FROM Tab1 t1
             where  t2.b = t1.a and
                    t2.c= t1.c 
             FOR XML PATH('concat'), Type
         ).Value('/concat[1]', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1,'') AS ACCEPTED_SYMBOLS
from Tab1 t2;
```

What this does is it create the string concatenation in XML and then converts it back from XML to a string.  The benefit is that the characters `&`, `<`, and `>` are not turned into their XML equivalent (`&mp;`, for instance) and remain as what you expect.

Comment: .Value should be lowercase: .value